# Difference between Hmisc::describe() and base::mean()

Tags: r, mean

I am currently using the function `Hmisc::describe()` to work on a dataset, but I am a bit confused by the fact that I get different mean results between the mean from that function and `base::mean()`:

```
> describe(df$a)
df$a 
         n    missing   distinct       Info       Mean        Gmd        .05 
     43916          0      32913          1 -7.246e-22  0.0007657 -0.0011175 
       .10        .25        .50        .75        .90        .95 
-0.0008658 -0.0004541  0.0000000  0.0004541  0.0008658  0.0011175 

lowest : -0.002721940 -0.002630613 -0.002584185 -0.002531125 -0.002504595
highest:  0.002504595  0.002531125  0.002584185  0.002630613  0.002721940
> mean(df$a)
[1] -1.255379e-21
```

What is the difference between the two ways of computing the mean? Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method shows `-7.246e-22`, while the second one `-1.255379e-21`. If you look at [R's documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/zMachine.html), the smallest possible double approaching zero (`double.eps`) is around `2.220446e-16`, so the displayed numbers fall below the numerical precision margin. They are simply so small, that they cannot be represented precisely as doubles. You can treat them as zeros. If you want to learn more about floating-point precision, I recommend the [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) paper by David Goldberg.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and for the paper!